# Sort merged QuerySets by created_at field

Tags: python, django, django-views

I try to sorted two merged QuerySets by `created_at` field and DESC (from max to min):

```
# app/views.py

class AccountIndexView(View):

    template_name = 'accounts/accounts_index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        # Get TVS object
        obj_1 = ModelOne.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        obj_2 = ModelTwo.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        # Make orders object
        orders = sorted(
            chain(obj_1, obj_2),
            key=attrgetter('created_at')
        )

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'orders': orders})
```

But this way not working: QuerySet still sorting by ID and ASC (from min to max). How to solve that with my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I founded solution in Python Docs:

> Both `list.sort()` and `sorted()` accept a `reverse` parameter with a boolean value. This is used to flag descending sorts. For example, to get the student data in reverse age order:

```
>>> student_tuples = [('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10), ('john', 'A', 15)]
>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
[('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#ascending-and-descending